# How to close all neural network diagrams in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, window-handles

I need to show diagrams of some networks, but the problem is that `close all` doesn't close these windows, so I have several windows to close manually after a few runs.

```
[x,t] = house_dataset;
net1 = newff(x, t, [5, 3]);
view(net1);
net2 = newff(x, t, [7, 5]);
view(net2);
close all;
```

However if I keep the handle of window, `close` function will close it:

```
net3 = newff(x, t, [9, 7]);
h = view(net3);
close(h);
```

But it's not easy for me to collect all those handles. How can I find all those handles programmatically?

Comment: Try **`close all force`**. Read the [**documentation**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html) for more!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama  doesn't work for me! BTW, I'm using R2016a.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command:

```
nnet.guis.closeAllViews()
```

This will close all the diagrams for the networks.