# How to close Neural Network Training Window and Self-Organizing Map using command line?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, matlab-figure, self-organizing-maps

How can I close the two windows that the following MATLAB SOM example creates, from the command line?

```
>> x = simplecluster_dataset;
>> net = selforgmap([8 8]);
>> net = train(net,x);
>> view(net)
>> y = net(x);
>> classes = vec2ind(y);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code opens two windows which are: *Neural Network Training Window* and Self-*Organizing Map*.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/nntraintool.html), **`nntraintool close`** is for closing Neural Network Training Window and as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41122228/5698672), **`nnet.guis.closeAllViews()`** is for closing all diagrams of the Neural Networks.

If you are using multiple *nnet guis views* and want to close only a specific view, assign a handle to that particular view and then use [**`close`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html) to close it. i.e. replace **`view(net)`** with **`h = view(net)`**, now when you use, **`close(h)`**, it'll close that particular *nnet gui view*.